# how to make voting system like stackoverflow using ajax/jquery/php (efficient)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

I'm trying to make post voting something similar to stack overflow vote up and vote down, now I made it work with (but-it-works approach) and yet something doesn't feel right, hopefully someone will suggest some useful tweaks. Here is my jquery code :

```
 var x = $("strong.votes_balance").text();
   $("input.vote_down").click(function(){
     $.ajax({   
       type: "POST",  
       url: "http://localhost/questions/vote_down/4",   
       success: function()   
       {   
       $("strong.votes_balance").html((parseInt(x) - parseInt(1)));
       $("input[type=button]").hide();
       $(".thumbsup_hide").show();
       }   
      });  
    });


   $("input.vote_up").click(function(){
     $.ajax({   
       type: "POST",  
       url: "http://localhost/questions/vote_up/4",   
       success: function()   
       {   
       $("input[type=button]").hide();
       $("strong.votes_balance").html((parseInt(x) + parseInt(1)));
       $(".thumbsup_hide").show();
       }   
       });
    });


    });
```

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="thumbsup thumbsup_template_up-down" id="thumbsup_49">


 <form method="post" id="voting_form">

<input type="hidden" value="49" name="thumbsup_id"/>
  <span class="thumbsup_hide">Result:</span>
  <strong class="votes_balance"><?=$row_q->post_vote?></strong>

  <input type="button" title="Good Comment!" value="+1" name="thumbsup_rating" class="vote_up"/>
  <input type="button" title="Bad Comment!" value="-1" name="thumbsup_rating" class="vote_down"/>
 </form>

</div>
```

$row_q->post_vote equals some number. Now when I click the vote up button it increments the value of strong and if I click vote down it decrements it.

I'm working with CI(codeigniter) not native php.

How do I measure performance of this, not so long ago vote up or vote down took more than two seconds to perform, I added LIMIT 1 to my query and now it works somewhat faster, I think this should perform lot faster. Thank you for your comments

And yes sorry for ommiting this here are my vote up and vote down functions :

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE $table SET $what_field = ($what_field + 1) $wheremore WHERE $what_id = '$value' LIMIT 1");
```

AND VOTE DOWN BELOW:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE $table SET $what_field = ($what_field - 1) $wheremore WHERE $what_id = '$value' LIMIT 1");
```

**UPDATE** I think the reason why things are generaly slow is because of my inexpirience with jquery, I think my table is okey

**UPDATE II**

I just removed the php part from the jquery ajax function, just to increment the number by 1 and it still works really slow.

**UPDATE III**

When I run query with phpmyadmin it runs from range 0.3 second until 1.77 seconds it varies for some reason.

Comment: Which database engine you are using?

Comment: Don't forget the `Who` in voting.

Comment: @Juha I'm using Mysql ,
@ Martijn - I'll worry about those things later I'm just trying to improve the performance

Comment: To take jQuery out of it: try to make a normal HTML form where you can POST against your vote-up URL http://localhost/questions/vote_up/4. If that's taking just as long, it's not jQuery.

Comment: You could also remove the query for now, and see if that makes a difference. If it doesn't, it's something else in your code (maybe the startup phase of loading your app and all its configuration is what takes the most amount of time?).

Comment: would you please tell me how to detect answer we are voting since i am showing answer by storing the question id on answer my query looks like (SELECT * FROM answer WHERE question_id ={id} )

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> WHERE $what_id = '$value'
> ```

You shouldn't use strings/varchars as identifiers. It's unnatural. Use numbers/integers.

```
WHERE $what_id = $value
```

Yes, this has influence on DB performance, especially when the rowcount gets high.

Comment: but even if I use just jquery with no php, just to change .text() of the strong element it takes sometimes more than a second to perform, is there a way I can measure jquery execution time ? +1 for now . tnx

Answer (score 1):

Your database table `$table` should have an index on `$what_id`. Normally it would be the primary key, but since adding `LIMIT 1` changed anything this likely is not the case?

Comment: Strange, an update with a single `WHERE primarykey = <id>` as condition shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds. What's in `$wheremore` by the way?

Comment: I agree its very strange, currently $wheremore is empty variable, I just put it there because I'll add date to it and many more things. Now I remove the php part from the jquery ajax function, just to increment the number by 1 and it still works really slow.

Answer (score 0):

What does your database look like? Make sure that `$what_id` field is properly indexed, preferably it should be the primary key if possible.

Comment: Yes it is the primary and it is properly indexed